# How to send suggestion buttons when on contactRelationUpdate event

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots

the `contactRelationUpdate` event has one argument for `message`, but as far as I know for building the message with attachments we need to have `session` to create new message through `new Message(session)`. Is there a way to to do or this is restriction.

Basically I want to send suggestion button first time user connected to my channel on Skype or Messenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuo can try following code:

```
bot.on('contactRelationUpdate', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    let card = {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
        "content": {
            "title": "options",
            "buttons": [{
                "type": "postBack",
                "value": "value",
                "title": "button 1"
            }]
        }
    };
    if (message.action == 'add') {
        bot.send(new builder.Message()
            .address(message.address)
            .addAttachment(card)
        )
    }
})
```